# Tomcat not running for a JAR file

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jar

I am using Postman alongside a JAR file that runs a REST service that holds some contacts. However when I try to run the JAR file by using: `java -jar ContactListRESTService.jar` in Powershell, I am seeing a bunch of errors that Apache Tomcat could not run. Postman also doesn't recognize the localhost.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tomcat connector in failed state
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:159)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tomcat connector in failed state
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletCntainer.java:159) ~[spring-boot 1.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.7.RELEASE]
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling JAVA SE per some guidance from a mentor with no results.

If anyone can point me in the right direction please.

Comment: there should be a bigger stack trace than that with the actual root cause.

Comment: seems like there are more than one tomcat instance trying to run.